# My webpack just stopped working.

Tags: javascript, wordpress, webpack, wordpress-theming, webpack-2

I have been using webpack and yarn for a while now, to build this wordpress project using a theme from underscores.me, only recently my webpack does not seem to compile my sass anymore. If i make changes to my sass file they do not show up in the site. The webpack it self seems to run fine without error when i run webpack --watch but even if i delebrately write a wrong code in my scss the webpack don't even detects it. It does not seem to be away of what is happening.

Here is my configuration:

```
//webpack.config.js

var webpack = require('webpack');
var GoogleFontsPlugin = require("google-fonts-webpack-plugin");

// exports the node module
module.exports = function(env) {
'use strict';

return {
  entry: "./js/app.js",
    output: {
      path: __dirname + "/dist",
      filename: "bundle.js"
  },

  /* ... */
  plugins: [
      new GoogleFontsPlugin({
          fonts: [

              { family: "Source Sans Pro" },
              { family: "Raleway", variants: [ "400", "600","900", "700italic", "Regular", "Medium","Bold","Extra-Bold", "Black"] }
          ]

          /* ...options */
      })
  ],

  module: {
        loaders: [
            {
              test: /\.html$/,
              loader: 'raw-loader',
              exclude: /node_modules/
            },
           {
              test   : /\.css$/,
              loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'resolve-url-loader', "postcss-loader"]
            }, {
              test   : /\.scss$/,
              loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'resolve-url-loader', 'sass-loader?sourceMap']
            },
            {
                test: /\.woff($|\?)|\.woff2($|\?)|\.ttf($|\?)|\.eot($|\?)|\.svg($|\?)/,
                 loader: 'url-loader'
            },
            // the url-loader uses DataUrls.
            // the file-loader emits files.
            {
              test: /\.woff2?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
              // Limiting the size of the woff fonts breaks font-awesome ONLY for the extract text plugin
              // loader: "url?limit=10000"
              use: "url-loader"
            },
            {
              test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?[\s\S]+)?$/,
              use: 'file-loader'
            },
            {
                // I want to uglify with mangling only app files, not thirdparty libs
                test: /.*\/app\/.*\.js$/,
                exclude: /.spec.js/, // excluding .spec files
                loader: "uglify"
            },
            {
                test: /\.(gif|png|jpe?g|svg)$/i,
                loaders: [
                  'file-loader', {
                    loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
                    options: {
                      gifsicle: {
                        interlaced: false
                      },
                      optipng: {
                        optimizationLevel: 7
                      },
                      pngquant: {
                        quality: '65-90',
                        speed: 4
                      },
                      mozjpeg: {
                        progressive: true,
                        quality: 65
                      },
                      // Specifying webp here will create a WEBP version of your JPG/PNG images
                      webp: {
                        quality: 75
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Does webpack recognize your changes? Does it say it compiles successfully?

Comment: PLEASE IS ALL MY BAD, AS I WAS NAVIGATING TO THE SECOND WORDPRESS PROJECT I WAS BUILDING USING WORDPRESS ALSO, AND I WAS RUNNING THE webpack --watch from this (a wrong directory).

My bad just figured it out and viola!! it is working perfectly.